# Silent arecord recordings

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm using a 32-channel in/out USB class-compliant audio device.  (Behringer X32 with an X-UF card installed.)  I'm trying to record from those channels on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Jessie.

```
arecord --buffer-size=88200 --device=hw:CARD=XUF,DEV=0 --format S32_LE --rate 44100 -c 32 testrec3.wav
```

This creates a WAV file with 32 channels, at 44.1 kHz, 32-bit, as expected.  I can open the file with Audacity.  However, all the channels are perfectly silent.  Trying to play back the file with `aplay`, it seems to play back for the appropriate amount of time but is totally silent.

I tested the device under Windows to verify the channels were set up on the X32... they were, and it worked fine.

I believe `arecord` is hitting the right device, because it won't work unless I specify 32 channels, the right sample rate, and the right sample format.  If I get those parameters wrong, I receive an error, as expected.  If I change the sample rate on the X32 to 48 kHz, I had to change the sample rate on the `arecord` parameters, as expected.

If I run `alsamixer`, I don't get any VU meters... just a message:

> This sound device does not have any controls.

This is expected.  My device shouldn't have any software-controllable anything.  Just channels in, channels out.  I was hoping for some VU meters though to show what's happening, but AlsaMixer doesn't seem to do that unless there's a controllable mixer.

How can I further debug this issue?  What can I check to figure out why the recording is silent?

Here's the device list:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: XUF [X_UF], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=XUF
    X_UF, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=XUF,DEV=0
    X_UF, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Running `amixer contents` or `amixer -c1 contents` returns nothing.  (`amixer -c0 contents` dues return some things, but that's for the built-in audio, not my USB device.)

There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in /var/log/syslog or dmesg.

Here's the output of `arecord --dump-hw-params`:

```
HW Params of device "default":
--------------------
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S32_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 32
FRAME_BITS: 1024
CHANNELS: 32
RATE: 44100
PERIOD_TIME: (136 92880)
PERIOD_SIZE: [6 4096]
PERIOD_BYTES: [768 524288]
PERIODS: [2 1024]
BUFFER_TIME: (272 185760)
BUFFER_SIZE: [12 8192]
BUFFER_BYTES: [1536 1048576]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
```

`lsusb`:

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1397:0006 BEHRINGER International GmbH

`cat /proc/version`:

> Linux version 4.4.50-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017

`usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  2
P:  Vendor=1397 ProdID=0006 Rev=20.41
S:  Manufacturer=BEHRINGER
S:  Product=X_UF
S:  SerialNumber=0x156400fe24
C:  #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=20 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=20 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=20 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=01(audio) Sub=03 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56200/discussion-on-question-by-brad-silent-arecord-recordings).